# Any programs for Mac OSX like wyBuild for updating Mac apps

Tags: macos, air, installation, adobe

I have an app made with Adobe AIR that I am distributing on Windows, Mac, and other platforms. I am using the captive runtime feature so I can't use Adobe AIR's auto-update mechanism.

On Windows, I'm considering using [WyBuild](http://wyday.com/wybuild/), but it is Windows only. On the Mac, I see [Sparkle](http://sparkle.andymatuschak.org/) is a popular framework, but I think it's a no-go for me since I am not building the app in Xcode.

I could make my own update mechanism to prompt the user to download a new DMG when it is available, but I don't know if I can automatically install my new app without having the user go through that process.

Does anyone have a suggestion about automating the re-install process for an Adobe AIR captive runtime app on Mac OSX (10.6 and higher)?

Thanks!

-jonathan